# AJAX Call not working in liferay 6.2.2?

Tags: ajax, liferay, hook, liferay-6

I am trying to perform a `AJAX` Call. But what i get is `ResourceURL` as undefined when i see the error in chrome.

Below is my code.

Declaration:

```
<liferay-portlet:resourceURL copyCurrentRenderParameters="<%= false %>" var="mainURL" />
```

Implementation:

```
xhr2.open("POST", resourceURL , false);
```

But at implmentation i get `resourceURL` as undefined. In 6.1 it used to work fine. I dont know if there are any alternatives for using this. Please guide.

Comment: I think you need to use "mainURL" instead resourceURL

Comment: yes lucky boy i tried that too..didnt seem to work

Comment: Did you try using something like this ${mainURL} since its a variable

Comment: no i will give a try

Comment: it worked perfectly in 6.1 though

Comment: sorry bro not working....

Comment: Can you please post some more code? Is there any chances that you declared resource URL in jsp file and trying to use it in JS file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79783/discussion-between-lucky-boy-and-luxy).

Comment: On ajax call you have to use resource url var

Comment: Use like this: xhr2.open("POST", <%=mainURL %>, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thanks to Olaf Cock and Gevatterajan for their guidance. First issue was:
to replace `varImpl` with `var` and also to remove `copyCurrentRenderParameters` while i was migrating from 6.1 to 6.2.
The defination should have been like this:

```
<liferay-portlet:resourceURL var="mainURL" />
```

Similarly we have to repeat for `renderURL` and other URLs while we are working on 6.2. And mostly i was missing some of the important imports which were mention in my view.jsp.
For eg for `editFileEntryURL` which was mentioned in my `view.jsp` its implementation was mentioned in `view_entries.jsp`. Below is the implmentation code.

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="editFileEntryURL">
    <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/dlsample" />
    <portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="<%= Constants.ADD %>" />
    <portlet:param name="repositoryId" value='<%= "" + repositoryId %>' />
    <portlet:param name="folderId" value='<%= "" + folderId %>' />
    <portlet:param name="workflowAction" value='<%= "" + WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH %>' />
    <portlet:param name="displayStyle" value="<%= displayStyle %>" />
    <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
</portlet:resourceURL>
```

I organised my imports properly and yes now my code has started working..Cheers.